# Append string to existing value in column of type nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have a database table "table_2" in Microsoft SQL Server 2016 DB.

```
CREATE TABLE table_2
(
    [created_date] [date] NULL,
    [complete_hour] [int] NULL,
    [col_percent] [float] NULL,
    [notes] [nvarchar] (400)
)

INSERT INTO table_2
VALUES ('2017-05-31', 10, 5.8, 'A'),
       ('2019-06-14', 11, 9.9, NULL)
```

Now I want to append `', B'` to the values in column notes if column notes has value that is:

1. NOT NULL and
2. NOT empty and
3. NOT 'B'

I want to add/insert/append 'B' in column notes if column notes has NULL value.

**What I have tried:**

```
UPDATE table_2 
SET notes=notes+', '+'B' 
WHERE col_percent = 5.8
```

But it throws error:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Line 14
>   String or binary data would be truncated.

When I try

```
UPDATE table_2 
SET notes=notes+', '+'B' 
WHERE col_percent = 9.9
```

It shows `(1 row affected)` but I see same data and column notes still has NULL in second row.

I did some looking around and seems that changing the data type of column notes from nvarchar to varchar(50) will resolve this issue. (I have tested it) But in real case I can't change data type.

**Question:** How can I do this without changing data type of column notes?

**Update:** Declared notes column as `[notes] [nvarchar] (400)`. This solves problem for non null values in column notes.

But for NULL values (like for col_percent = 9.9) it shows `(1 row affected)` but data is unchanged.

Zeina's solution does update when notes column has NULL but it adds leading comma as well.

**Solution I ended up using (there could be a better one than this):**

```
UPDATE table_2  
   SET notes = CASE
                   WHEN notes = 'B'   THEN 'B'
                   WHEN notes IS NULL THEN 'B' 
                   WHEN notes = ''    THEN 'B' 
                   ELSE notes+', '+'B'
               END 
 WHERE col_percent = 5.8
```

Comment: Since it's an `nvarchar`, you should really be declaring your literal string as an `nvarchar` too; which means prefixing your string with an N: `N'Your Literal String'`

Answer (score 6):

You *have to* change the type of `notes`.  Currently, you have defined `notes` as:

```
[notes] [nvarchar] NULL
```

You have not included a length, so SQL Server uses the default length.  In this context, the default length is 1, so you can only store one character in the column.

Then to handle `NULL` values, use `CASE`:

```
UPDATE table_2
    SET notes = (CASE WHEN notes IS NOT NULL THEN notes + ', ' +'B'
                 END)
    WHERE col_percent = 9.9;
```

Or, better yet:

```
UPDATE table_2
    SET notes = notes + ', ' +'B'
    WHERE col_percent = 9.9 AND notes IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Gordon Linoff. I have declared the notes column with length now and that did resolve it for non NULL values in column notes. For NULL values, (like for col_percent = 9.9) it shows (1 row affected) but data is unchanged. Zeina's solution is updating for NULL values as well. So I am just trying to come up with a single SQL for both NULL as well as NOT NULL.

Comment: @300 . . . That part is easy.  Just use `COALESCE()`.

Comment: Using `COALESCE()` was updating for `NULL` but was adding `, B`. I wanted `B` to be added when NULL and `, B` to be appended to existing values for NON NULL. I ended up using CASE statement for this as I mentioned in me reply. `COALESCE()` might also do it with some modifications but I didn't try it. Also I replaced `+` with `'` in COALESCE() to correct syntax error from your suggestion.

Comment: @300 . . . If you move the condition to the `WHERE` clause, you don't even need a `CASE`.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table_2 SET notes=ISNULL(notes, '') + ', B' WHERE col_percent=9.9
```

Since NULL in operation with any other value is considered as NULL. so we have first to place a default value for NULL cells, then append the B to it.

In case you needed to place 'B' only if the field was NULL you can use the following syntax:

```
UPDATE table_2 
SET notes =
           (CASE WHEN ISNULL(notes, '') = '' THEN 'B' 
                 ELSE ISNULL(notes, '') + ', B' END)
WHERE col_percent=9.9
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Zeina. Your suggestion is closest to what I want. Only problem is I can't use same SQL to update NULL values as it'll add `, B`. In case of NULL I want only `B` to be added. Trying to see if I can get both NULL and NOT NULL taken care of with single SQL.